# Wrapper for getter and setter methods in c++

Tags: c++

I have few classes with pair of methods which stands for "setter" and "getter" methods, like:

```
class ClassA
{
    void SetSomeProperty(const int& value) { ... }
    int GetSomeProperty() { ... }

    void SetAnotherProperty(const Vec3& value) { ... }
    Vec3 GetAnotherProperty() { ... }
};

class ClassB
{
    void SetColor(const Vec4& value) { ... }
    Vec4 GetColor() { ... }
}
```

I want to create a class called PropertyAccess that can wrap each pair of setter and getter of any class. This will allow me to past this PropertyAccess to other object which will be able to call those setters and getters wihout any knowledgne about ClassA or ClassB.

this is my iplementation:

```
class PropertyAccess
{
public:
    template <typename TClass, typename TType> using SetterPointer = void (TClass::*)(const TType&);
    template <typename TClass, typename TType> using GetterPointer = TType(TClass::*)();

    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    PropertyAccess(
        TClass* object,
        SetterPointer<TClass, TType> setter,
        GetterPointer<TClass, TType> getter)
    {
        using std::placeholders::_1;
        m_setter = new Setter<TType>(std::bind(setter, object, _1));
        m_getter = new Getter<TType>(std::bind(getter, object));
    }

    ~PropertyAccess()
    {
        delete m_setter;
        delete m_getter;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Set(const T& value)
    {
        ((Setter<T>*)m_setter)->m_setter(value);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T Get()
    {
        return ((Getter<T>*)m_getter)->m_getter();
    }

private:
    struct Base
    {
        virtual ~Base() {}
    };

    template <typename TType>
    struct Setter : public Base
    {
        Setter(std::function < void(const TType&) > setter) { m_setter = setter; }

        std::function < void(const TType&) > m_setter;
    };

    template <typename TType>
    struct Getter : public Base
    {
        Getter(std::function < TType() > getter) { m_getter = getter; }

        std::function < TType() > m_getter;
    };

    Base* m_setter;
    Base* m_getter;
};
```

I use it like that:

```
ClassA a;
PropertyAccess p(&a, &ClassA::SetSomeProperty, &ClassA::GetSomeProperty);
p.Set<int>(10);
int v = p.Get<int>();
```

Everything works fine, but this is exteremly slow approach. Calling setters through PropertAccess is approx 18 times slower than call them directly. Speed is important here, because I need to use that mechanism in animation library (Animator will set properties without knowledge about source objects).

So my question is: how to speed up this mechanism? Is there any "industry standard" approach for that? Maybe I should use classic method pointers instead of std::function?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the setter and getter method pointers in function and bind? Why not just store the pointers and call them directly.

Comment: Except of pointers I also need to store type of class and object on which those pointers will be called.

Comment: you're storing all of that in binds and functions anyway, at the expense as well because it is duplicated and causes all the slowness you're experiencing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take Anton Slavin's solution and introduce an interface to erase object type. It will make lifetime management of accessors more complicated (you'll have to use references/pointers/smart pointers and manage lifetime because you won't be able to copy accessors) and will cost at runtime as virtual method calls will not inline so I would measure if it is quicker than your original solution.

```
template<typename TType>
struct PropertyAccess
{
    virtual void Set(const TType& value) = 0;
    virtual TType Get() = 0;
};

template <typename TClass, typename TType>
class PropertyAccessT : public PropertyAccess<TType>
{
public:
    using SetterPointer = void (TClass::*)(const TType&);
    using GetterPointer = TType(TClass::*)();

    PropertyAccessT(TClass* object, SetterPointer setter, GetterPointer getter)
        : m_object(object), m_setter(setter), m_getter(getter)
    {
    }

    void Set(const TType& value) {
        (m_object->*m_setter)(value);
    }

    TType Get() {
        return (m_object->*m_getter)();
    }

private:

    TClass* m_object;
    SetterPointer m_setter;
    GetterPointer m_getter;
};
```

Comment: Yes, it looks faster imho;) I will make some tests. Anyway, do you think that idea of PropertyAccess is good? I mean is this good direction to handle my needs of setting and getting value of properties of unknown objects?

Comment: If this is your requirement then sure you need something like this. If you're using C++11 maybe lambdas would be another solution to replace bind in your original solution and it might perform well with a good optimising compiler. I would encourage to keep the api type safe though i.e. avoid erasing the property type.

Comment: My oryginal solution is 17.848 times slower than directly call, PropertyAccess 2.112 times slower and PropertyAccessT 2.110 times slower. So yes, it is faster;) Virtual calls overhead is irelevant. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Make `PropertyAccess` itself a template:

```
template <typename TClass, typename TType>
class PropertyAccess
{
public:
    using SetterPointer = void (TClass::*)(const TType&);
    using GetterPointer = TType(TClass::*)();

    PropertyAccess(TClass* object, SetterPointer setter, GetterPointer getter)
        : m_object(object), m_setter(setter), m_getter(getter)
    {
    }

    void Set(const TType& value) {
        (m_object->*m_setter)(value);
    }

    TType Get() {
        return (m_object->*m_getter)();
    }

private:

    TClass* m_object;
    SetterPointer m_setter;
    GetterPointer m_getter;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e90738982c515ef7)

Your current implementation is not only slow, it's unsafe. See what happens if you do

```
ClassA a;
PropertyAccess p(&a, &ClassA::SetSomeProperty, &ClassA::GetSomeProperty);
p.Set<double>(10); // but property is int
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the type of object to be erased though

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin anyway they have to know the type when calling `Set` and especially `Get()` where it can't be deduced.

Comment: Yes, correct type of the property is a must, however we can lose the type of the object where that property belongs.

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin, thats true, I want PropertyAccess to be non templated class. Objects that will use PropertyAccess will know the type of setter and getter, but will not know about the type of source object.